# fourier() vs fourierf() function in R

Tags: r, forecasting, decomposition

I'm using the `fourier()` and `fourierf()` functions in Ron Hyndman's excellent `forecast` package in R.  Looking to verify whether the same terms are selected and used in `fourier()` and `fourierf()`, I plotted a few of the output terms.

Below is the original data using `ts.plot(data)`.  There's a frequency of 364 in the time series, FYI.  [image: data]

Below is the plot of the terms using `fourier(data,3)`.  Basically, it looks like mirror images of the existing data.

[image: fourier]

Looking at just the sin1 term of the output, again, we get some variation that shows similar 364-day seasonality in line with the data above.

[image: fourier2]

However, when I plot the results of the Fourier forecast using `fourierf(data,3, 410)` I see the below data.  It appears far more smooth than the terms provided by the original `fourier` function. 
[image: fourierf]

So, I wonder how the results of `fourier()` and `fourierf()` are related. Is it possible to just see one consolidated Fourier result, so that you can see the sin or cosine result moving through existing data and then through the forecasting period?  If not, how can I confirm that the terms created by `fourierf()` fit the in-sample data?

I want to use it in an `auto.arima` or `glm` function with other external regressors like this:

```
 trainFourier<-fourier(data,3)

 trainFourier<-as.data.frame(trainFourier)
 trainFourier$exogenous<-exogenousData
 arima.object<-auto.arima(data, xreg=trainFourier)

 futureFourier<-fourierf(data,3, 410)

 fourierForecast<-forecast(arima.object, xreg=futureFourier, h=410)
```

and want to be completely sure that the auto.arima has the proper fitting (using the terms from `fourier()`) to what I'll put in under xreg for `forecast` (which has terms from a different function, i.e. `ffourier()`).

Answer (score 12):

Figured out the problem.  I was using both the `fda` and `forecast` packages.  `fda`, which is for functional data analysis and regression, has its own `fourier()` function. If I detach `fda`, my S1 term from `fourier(data,3)` looks like this:

[image: fourier()]

which lines up nicely with the Fourier forecast if I use `ts.plot(c(trainFourier$S1,futureFourier$S1))`

Moral of the story -- watch what your packages supress, folks!